# Plist/Document Directory is null when reading plist

Tags: objective-c

I just want to replace static plist data to dynamic.this is my code

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *docDirPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.plist"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: docDirPath])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"plist"];


    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:docDirPath error:&error];

    NSLog(@"plist is copied to Directory");
}
```

i have some data in event array but its not writing/reading can you please suggest me where i am wrong.

```
NSLog(@"data coming from server....%@",self.eventDataArray);

        //Writing array to document directory
        NSArray *docpaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [docpaths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sample.plist", documentsDirectoryPath];
        [self.eventDataArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

        NSLog(@"plist path string....%@",path);


        //reading from document directory
        NSMutableArray *readingArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        NSLog(@"plist reading data is here......%@",readingArray);
```

Comment: assert that self.eventDataArray isn't nil either

Comment: I tried with self but still its null.

Comment: assert that bundle isn't nil then ;)